# How to organize cross-platform projects with Git repository?

Tags: xcode, git, visual-c++, cross-platform

I have a VST plug-in project that I am developing that has just reached a beta stage.  I am supporting both OS X and Windows, and the way I organized this up until now was to store all the C++ source code in Dropbox, but have each project and platorm-specific files stored locally.  That way I kept all the C++ source files synched and could easily jump back and forth between Xcode and Visual C++.

Now I need to start source control on the project (using Git) and I'm wondering how to keep the same sort of functionality/organization.  My initial thought would be to store the source code in the master branch and then having the Xcode and Visual C++ projects in separate branches.  Then I would check out the project on whatever platform I'm working on.  But would this keep the source code synched?

Repositories are a bit new to me, so I'm just trying to wrap my head around it and make sure I don't make a disaster in trying to keep this and future cross-platform projects organized.  Thanks for any assistance and advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the shared code in it's own repository and add it as a submodule in the platform specific repositories.

Details [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

> Repositories are a bit new to me, so I'm just trying to wrap my head
>   around it and make sure I don't make a disaster in trying to keep this
>   and future cross-platform projects organized.

Git definitely has a steep learning curve, but it's very flexible and you can easily change you mind later if you decide to organize your code in another way. It's also very hard to delete something and not be able to restore it. Actually you have to try really hard to get rid of something completely ;)